# How to install boot-repair on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub

Is there any way to install the boot-repair on Ubuntu 21.10 I have checked the official site and their PPA method doesn't have any release file for this version of Ubuntu, So how to download it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to use the `focal` version instead.

You can either manually edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-impish.list` to look like the following:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ focal main

# Enable again when PPA gets updated.
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ impish main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ impish main
```

or you can use `Software & Updates`, switch to the `Other Software` tab, find the `http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/` entry, click on `Edit...` and change `Distribution` to `focal`.

`sudo apt install boot-repair` should now work.